# Why is the Fourier transform of $f(x)=x$ on $[0,1]$, $0$ otherwise, apparently not square integrable?

Tags: calculus, fourier-analysis

Let the function $f(x)=x$ if $x\in[0,1]$ and $f(x)=0$ otherwise. The function is in $L_2$.

Unless mistaken, the Fourier transform of f is $\hat f(\xi)=\int_0^1{xe^{ix\xi}dx}=e^{i\xi}(1/\xi^2-i/\xi) - 1/\xi^2$.

$\hat f$ explodes around zero as $\xi$ appears in the denominator. I thought that Fourier transform was an isometry on $L_2$ (using Parseval's theorem), but $\hat f$ does not seem to be square-integrable.

Can you please explain to me what I am missing?

Comment: No, $$\frac{e^{i\xi} - 1 - i\xi e^{i\xi}}{\xi^2}$$ is well-behaved at $0$.

Comment: Gosh, it indeed is. Thank you very much.

Comment: Harmonic analysis is saved!

Comment: From the direct form, $\hat{f}(\xi)=\int_{0}^{1}xe^{-ix\xi}dx$ you can see that $\hat{f}$ is infinitely differentiable.

Answer (score 1):

The Fourier transform of $f(x)=x\cdot\mathbb{1}_{(0,1)}(x)$ is given by:

$$\widehat{f}(\xi)=\int_{0}^{1} x\, e^{-i x \xi}\,dx=\frac{(1+i\xi)e^{-i\xi}-1}{\xi^2} $$
hence:
$$\widehat{f}(\xi)\cdot\overline{\widehat{f}(\xi)}=\frac{2+\xi^2-2\cos\xi-2\xi\sin\xi}{\xi^4}=\frac{1}{4}-\frac{\xi^2}{72}+O(\xi^4)\quad\left(\xi\to 0\right)$$
and that function is clearly integrable.

Comment: @user252766: you're welcome.